# Jackson serialiazation with @JsonIdentityInfo does not add identity info to object with no properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

*Update: I've removed the original code as it was just confusing, only the simplified code needs to be here.  If you want to see more detail about what I'm doing, it's in the edit history.*

I have a data structure I'm attempting to serialize with Jackson.  One of the items in this structure is a POJO that exists just to facilitate communication between different items that have references to it.  It is therefore important that they hold the same reference, not different ones.

The problem is that despite having an appropriate `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation on the class, the `@id` property is not generated.  If I add a serialized property to the class, then the `@id` property is generated just fine.  But there are no properties that I want this object to actually have: the point is simply that all the instances are shared.  Is there any way I can force Jackson to generate the id property despite the object itself having no properties?

Here's a simplified test case:

```
public class Test
{
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
    public static class TestObject
    {
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject ();
        new ObjectMapper ()
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter ()                      
            .writeValue (System.out, testObject);

    }
}
```

Running this program gives the result:

```
{
  "@c" : ".Test$TestObject"
}
```

Changing the TestObject class to:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public static class TestObject
{
    private int testProperty;

    public int getTestProperty ()
    {
        return testProperty;
    }

    public void setTestProperty (int testProperty)
    {
        this.testProperty = testProperty;
    }
}
```

gives the result:

```
{
  "@c" : ".Test$TestObject",
  "@id" : 1,
  "testProperty" : 0
}
```

This is closer to what I want, but I do not want the "testProperty" generated.  How do I get rid of it?  If I simply annotate it with `@JsonIgnore` we go back to the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug in Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/370), which has apparently now been fixed in the git repo, and the fix is scheduled to make it into release 2.3.1.